# jquery ajax file upload with progressbar uploading same file multiple times

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jquery-file-upload

i am creating media-bank where user can upload media files and can reuse later

image,audio and videos can be uploaded with the following options
image upload from pc, specify link
audio upload from pc, specify link
video  upload from pc, youtube url, facebook embed code

separate forms are created in tabbed layout with `class="FormUpload"`
`upload from pc forms` has `<input type="file" name="file".../>`
while all other forms has `<textarea name="file" ...>`

my database table looks like
`[id, file,                  type,    src,...]`
`[1,  pic.png,               image,   pc,...]`
`[2,  http://domin/img.png,  image,   link,...]`

```
$('body').on('submit','.FormUpload',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var pr = $(this).parents('.tabPanes').find('.progressBar');
            var lbl = $(this).parents('.tabPanes').find('.percentLabel');
            var url = $(this).attr('action');

            var data = new FormData();
            if($(this).find('#txtFile[type="file"]').length === 1 ){
                data.append('file', $(this).find( '#txtFile' )[0].files[0]);
            }else{
                data.append('file', $(this).find('#txtFile' ).val());
            }
            data.append('type',$(this).find('#txtType').val());
            data.append('src',$(this).find('#txtSrc').val());
            data.append('title',$(this).find('#txtTitle').val());
            data.append('tags',$(this).find('#txtTags').val());

            if($(this).find('#txtFile[type="file"]').length === 1){//if file is being uploaded from pc
                pr.val(100);
                fileForm(url,data,pr,lbl);
            }else{//else link is provided
                linkForm(url,data,pr,lbl);
                pr.val(0);
            }

            return false;
        });


function fileForm(url,data,pr,lbl){
    `enter code here`$.ajax({
        url : url,
        type: "POST",
        data : data,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData:false,
        xhr: function(){
            //upload Progress
            var xhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
            if (xhr.upload) {
                xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(event) {
                    var percent = 0;
                    var position = event.loaded || event.position;
                    var total = event.total;
                    if (event.lengthComputable) {
                        percent = Math.ceil(position / total * 100);
                    }
                    pr.val(percent);
                }, false);
            }
            return xhr;
        },
        mimeType:"multipart/form-data",
    }).done(function(res){ //
        frm[0].reset();
        lbl.html(res);
    });
```

`linkForm()` also looks like `fileForm()`

the issue is when I upload image from PC it uploads the same image 3-times some time 5-times in folder as well as database.

I debuged and noticed network tab, ajax request to php file is also being sent multiple times.

tried to replace all jquery code by the following but still same issue but this time frequency looks reduced

```
    $('body').on('submit','.FormUpload',function(e){
e.preventDefault();  //prevent form normal submition

//get progressbar label url_to_hit and form_reference into variables to be used below
var pr = $(this).parents('.tabPanes').find('.progressBar');
var lbl = $(this).parents('.tabPanes').find('.percentLabel');
var url = $(this).attr('action');
var frm = $(this);

//populate formdata
var data = new FormData();
if(frm.find('#txtFile[type="file"]').length === 1 ){
    data.append('file', frm.find( '#txtFile' )[0].files[0]);
}else{
    data.append('file', frm.find('#txtFile' ).val());
}
data.append('type',frm.find('#txtType').val());
data.append('src',frm.find('#txtSrc').val());
data.append('title',frm.find('#txtTitle').val());
data.append('tags',frm.find('#txtTags').val());

//prepare ajax and callback functions
var ajax  = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax.upload.addEventListener('progress',function(evt){
    var percentage = (evt.loaded/evt.total)*100;
    pr.val(Math.round(percentage));
    lbl.html(Math.round(percentage)+'% uploaded.');
},false);
ajax.addEventListener('load',function(evt){
    lbl.html(evt.target.responseText);
    pr.val(0);
},false);
ajax.addEventListener('error',function(evt){
    lbl.html('upload failed');
    pr.val(0);
},false);
ajax.addEventListener('abort',function(evt){
    lbl.html('upload aborted');
    pr.val(0);
},false);
ajax.open('POST',url);
ajax.send(data);

//again stop form submition (optional)
return false;
});
```